# Python: Nulls are getting dropped by pd.get_dummies()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`. It consists of both numeric and categorical variables with NaN/NULL values in it. To proceed with my data pre-processing, I have to one-hot-encode my categorical variables and I do that with `pd.get_dummies()`.

However, after using `.get_dummies`, the NULLs that were in the original `df` are no longer present in the one-hot-encoded `df_ohe`. I'm wondering how the nulls are getting dropped in my new dataframe, `df_ohe`. I checked the documentation for `.get_dummies` but I don't see why the null observations are getting dropped.

```
df_ohe = pd.get_dummies(df.drop(['classLabel'], axis=1), drop_first=True)
```

The count of nulls by variable show that there are no nulls in the resulting table, `df_ohe`:

```
df_ohe.isnull().sum()
v2                0
v3                0
v5                0
v6                0
v7                0
v10               0
v13               0
v14               0
v15               0
v17               0
classLabel_int    0
v1_b              0
v4_u              0
v4_y              0
v8_t              0
v9_t              0
v11_t             0
v12_p             0
v12_s             0
v16_t             0
```

The original has nulls:

```
df.isnull().sum()
v1                  39
v2                  39
v3                   0
v4                  64
v5                   0
v6                   0
v7                   0
v8                   0
v9                   0
v10                  0
v11                  0
v12                  0
v13                100
v14                  0
v15                100
v16               2145
v17                  0
classLabel           0
classLabel_int       0
```

Why are my nulls getting dropped?

Comment: I don't see any dummies created else column names would have been different. Can you split the dropping the `classlabel` and creating dummies into 2 steps?

Comment: Is `dh_ohe` your first dataframe you create? If so, it's clear that there are no nulls in it.

Comment: If you're asking *why*, it's because nulls are ignored by `sum` by default in pandas.  If you look at the docs, there is an optional flag `skipna` which defaults to `True`

Comment: @user3483203 I start with a Pandas dataframe, `df`. It has nulls in it. I create `df_ohe` from `df`. `df_ohe` has no nulls. Why? All that should have been done is create a Pandas DataFrame with dummy variables.

Comment: are you talking about nulls in the categorical columns?

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz I'm talking about all variables. After `.get_dummies()`, no nulls appear to exist in the resulting table.

Comment: nulls in the categorical features will either be gone (0) or will be transformed to a new column (with a 1 in them) if you specify dummy_na=True  to get_dummies. The rest should still be there (at least that's what I see with pandas 0.23.1)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz in my code above, I do not specify the `dummy_na` parameter. The default value is `False`. So that is not the issue.

Comment: when it is false - the nulls are ignored - i.e. the newly created columns have 0s. if you'd specify dummy_na=True, you'd, for example, have another column v1_nan with 1's in it

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz ok. that is very helpful to know. i think that answers the question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have categorical values with Nulls/NaNs in them the nulls are ignored -i.e. you get 0 in the newly created columns, if you pass dummy_na=True parameter to the get_dummies call you'd still won't have nulls but you'd get new columns with 1 for null values e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'], [2, None],[np.nan,'f']])
df
```

[image]

```
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

[image]

row 1 column 1_a and 1_f has zeros

```
pd.get_dummies(df,dummy_na=True)
```

[image]

The categorical feature has a new column (1_nan) and the non-categorical is not affected

Answer (score 2):

NaN becomes 0 in your dummy variables. If you want keep null, try this:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, dummy_na=True)
```